# cassandra-stress error in cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.12.1046 | DSE 4.8.4

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I installed datastax enterprise, version as below, when I run stress test , get error below:

```
cqlsh> show version
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.12.1046 | DSE 4.8.4 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3]
[root@pg0 opt]# cassandra-stress write n=19000000 -rate threads=4
```

why get error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.
```

Comment: It looks like you're not specifying which node to you'd like the stress client to connect to. Try: cassandra-stress write n=19000000 -rate threads=4 -node <ip address>

Comment: when add ip, it's ok now, thx